# react native image from filesystem not displaying in ios

Tags: ios, react-native

The react native image does not appear but takes up space. It's a file on the phone's filesystem, NOT the camera roll. It's the product of react-native-image-editor.

Tried using path with and without 'file://' prefix. Works fine on android. If i take the uri from the IOS simulator and paste it into chrome the picture appears. Using picture from the web doesn't work either which makes me think it's something to do with the styling.

```
const ImageAnalysis = (props) => {
  const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;
  console.log(props.source);
  const imageSource = props.source;
  // const imagey = require(props.source.uri);
  const realPath =
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? imageSource.uri.replace('file://', '')
      : imageSource.uri;
  console.log(realPath);
  console.log(windowWidth);
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 2,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderBottomColor: colors.BrinkPink,
        // backgroundColor: colors.RoyalPurple,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
      }}>
      <Image
        source={{uri: props.source.uri}}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={{
          // position: 'relative',
          height: windowWidth / 3,
          width: windowWidth / 3,
          borderRadius: windowWidth / 3,
          margin: windowWidth / 12,
          alignSelf: 'center',
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug with React Native 0.63.0 and iOS 14. Upgrading to React Native 0.63.2 fixed it.